# Work done in circular expansion of a rubberband or an elastic wire

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, potential-energy, elasticity

What will be the work done in radially stretching a rubberband it can't be zero as there is potential energy being stored in it 
All I came up with it that there would be increase in overall length so assuming that initial length before expansion was $$2πR$$
And after its expansion it's$$ 2πx $$
I came up with the net energy or work done by external agent to be $$(K.2π(x^2-R^2))/2$$
 Is it correct or there is something else to be done that I am missing.
And if it were the case of an elastic wire have some Young's modulus what would be the energy stored in that case?

Comment: Even if you could treat the rubber as a linearly spring, the  $2\pi$'s should also be squared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the initial state (radius $R$) the rubber band is at rest. It's from
that configuration that energy is required for extending it. Then
elastic energy should increase quadratically from there. I would take as
potential elastic energy
$${\textstyle{1 \over 2}} K\,[2\pi\,(x - R)]^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

> Is it correct or there is something else to be done that I am missing.

What you're missing is that the stress-strain curves of rubbers tend not to be linear. Here are two examples:

[image: Stress strain]

[Source.](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-uniaxial-stress-strain-curves-of-neoprene-rubber-13-and-silicone_fig4_280573536)

That means that these materials don not have a constant Young's modulus, but rather:

$$E=f(\gamma)$$

Similarly, the spring 'constant' of a real rubber band will not be constant but:

$$K=g(x)$$

The potential energy stored upon extension is found from:

$$\Delta U=\int_0^xg(x)dx$$

Comment: But if hypothetically assuming that it's linear then will the expression I derived is correct?

Comment: @adityaprakash Yes.